How to broadcast transactions in bitcoin regtest mode?
I build three nodes named A,B,C based on bitcoin-regtest image of docker. And these three nodes are in the same network which means they can communicate with each other.
In node A, I use
bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=admin -rpcpassword=123456 addnode "$IPofB:18444" onetry

In node B, I use
bitcoin-cli -regtest -rpcuser=admin -rpcpassword=123456 addnode "$IPofC:18444" onetry

Then B is the peer node of A and C is the peer node of B;
I send a transaction from the wallet created on node A to wallet created on node C. And the sendtoaddress API is used on node A. The API works well and returns the transaction id. I can find the transaction in the transaction pool of A.
But I find some troubles:

I use tcpdump to catch the network flow. I find A broadcast the transaction to B. But C cannot receive from node B.
I cannot find the transaction from the transaction pool of node B and C;

I want to know whether regtest network of bitcoin can achieve what I need
